# CEP query based on date / time of the day

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

In WSO2 CEP, I made an execution plan that includes the following query:
(it will be fired if the temperature exeeds 20 degrees 3 times in a row within 10 seconds)

```
from MQTTstream[meta_temperature > 20]#window.time(10 sec) 
select count(meta_temperature) as meta_temperature
having meta_temperature > 3
insert into out_temperatureAlarm
```

How can I achieve that the query is only applied if it is a special time of the day, e.g. 08:00 until 10:00 o'clock?

Is there something that I could put into the query like:

```
having meta_temperature > 3 and HOUR_OF_THE_DAY BETWEEN 8 and 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cron window `#window.cron` instead of using a time window `#window.time`. You can specify Cron expression string for desired time periods in Siddhi [1]. Please refer quartz scheduler documentation to get more information on cron expression strings [2].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Inbuilt+Windows#InbuiltWindows-croncron

[2] http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Comment: If i set a cron.window like this: window.cron("0/10 0-30 11 * * ?"). The expression gets evaluated periodically every 10 seconds. But with the window.time the result returns imetiately after 3 events within 10 seconds occured. With the cron time window there could occur missed events if events happen right between two cron windows. Is it possible to circumvent that somehow?

Comment: Ah well I solved it by using one expression with a window.time, inserting the result into a temporary stream and a second expression using the temporary stream with window.cron. Maybe not elegant, but now it works the way I imagined. Thank you very much!